# How to give reference to magento register blocks?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Let us consider i am working with registration form and i want to add new field in it say "Company". here I know all the process of creating module and add field in `/customer/form/register.phtml` file, but i want to do it in different way.

Here is my query, i want to do this with the help of `xml` file in which i  create my new `xml` file and give reference to `customer_form_register` block with new `.phtml` file (without editing `/customer/form/register.phtml`) with all back end process of creating module same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

I now understand your question is asking if you can insert additional form fields on the customer register form without editing the `customer/form/register.phtml` template. Unfortunately, in Magento’s layout I don’t believe there is currently a way to create a reference to a block inside of another reference except from within the same. So, while there is not a very clean way to do this using only layout XML, there is one way you could accomplish it...

### A Possible Solution

In order to insert a new child block into the `customer_form_register` block, we need to override the layout definition for that block. That is not ideal because you replace any other definitions of that block, so you need to be careful to incorporate any other necessary layout updates into your new one as well. One to consider is that this block gets redefined in `captcha.xml`, so if you need that functionality you need to add in those updates to your new definition as well.

We will then be inserting a new block, `customer.form.register.newsletter`. This is because that child block name is already being invoked in the `register.phtml` template like this `$this->getChildHtml('customer.form.register.newsletter')`, but  it does not seem to be used for anything else that I noticed. So once we have defined our new block with this name, it will be inserted into the page below the existing newsletter checkbox:

```
<customer_account_create>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
            <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
                <label>Form Fields Before</label>
            </block>

            <!-- This is our new block. -->
            <block type="core/template" name="customer.form.register.newsletter" template="customer/form/custom_register.phtml"/>

        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account_create>
```

### Alternative

I think you may want to consider something like [this extension](https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Extensions/Magento-Custom-Registration-field.html) instead, since it seems to make it easy to add custom registration fields.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, your answer is right but i do'nt want to override the whole register.php, i want make register.phtml working and add my new field in it without editing register.phtml

Comment: @DeepakMankotia - I updated my answer based on your feedback. Does it meet the criteria you were looking for now?